# printing output using awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a text file which contain numbers

numbers.txt

```
a,1
b,2
c,2000
d,1001
e,4
f,3
```

I am trying to get all the values from column 2 and do a line count and print the total

```
awk -F, '{if($2 >= 0 && $2 <= 999) print "%10s" "%40s" , "Total", $2}' "numbers.txt" | sort -n | wc -l
```

It gives me only the output of this

```
4
```

if I use printf

```
awk -F, '{if($2 >= 0 && $2 <= 999) printf "%10s" "%40s" , "Total", $2}' "numbers.txt" | sort -n | wc -l
```

It gives me only the output of this

```
1
```

whereas I need the output to be like this

```
total 4
```

Comment: I think you might want to use `printf` instead of `print`.

Comment: if I use printf the output will become 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show all lines having the 2nd field in the `[0,999]` range and finally show how many of these columns are, then this can make it. No need to `sort -n` and `wc -l`, `awk` itself can do it:

```
$ awk -F, '($2 >= 0 && $2 <= 999) {printf "%10s %40s\n" , "Total", $2; i++} END{print "total: "i}' file
     Total                                        1
     Total                                        2
     Total                                        4
     Total                                        3
total: 4
```

And if you just want the sum:

```
$ awk -F, '($2 >= 0 && $2 <= 999) i++} END{print "total: "i}' file
total: 4
```

---

Why was your command not working?

With `print`:

```
$ awk -F, '{if($2 >= 0 && $2 <= 999) print "%10s" "%40s" , "Total", $2}' a | sort -n
%10s%40s Total 1
%10s%40s Total 2
%10s%40s Total 3
%10s%40s Total 4
```

The number of lines was ok, although the format was not: to use `%10s` you need to use `printf` instead.

With `printf`:

```
$ awk -F, '{if($2 >= 0 && $2 <= 999) printf "%10s" "%40s" , "Total", $2}' a
     Total                                       1     Total                                       2     Total                                       4     Total                                       3
```

As per using `printf` without printing new lines, all output was in the same line. You just needed to add `\n` at the end of each `printf`:

```
$ awk -F, '{if($2 >= 0 && $2 <= 999) printf "%10s %40s\n", "Total", $2}' file
     Total                                        1
     Total                                        2
     Total                                        4
     Total                                        3
```

Comment: I only want print the total of those numbers that are between 0 to 999

Comment: @user2211678 I updated explaining why your code was not working properly. You were pretty close, just a matter of printing new lines.